# How to save HTML page using webView.saveWebArchive() below API level 11?

Tags: android, html, api, android-webview, android-sdcard

I want to save the HTML page locally on the SD card and reuse it later.

I am able to do the same using

```
webView.saveWebArchive(filename);
```

But this method is not present below API level 11. How can I perform the same function with an API level below 11?

Comment: Anybody really need implement to quickly.:D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show page in webview when no internet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936973/show-page-in-webview-when-no-internet)