# show page in webview when no internet

Tags: android

I need to save page from webview then open it in webview. I found method saveWebArchive and wrote code:

```
        Timestamp tm = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
        String fileName = String.format("web_file_%d.mht",tm.getTime());

        String path = dir.toString() + File.separator + fileName;
        view.getWebView().saveWebArchive(path);
```

then I load page where model.getContentPath() is path from code above

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///"+model.getContentPath());
```

and I got page without CSS styels etc...
Can you say how to save and load page which will be looks like original from web?